# JavaFX and Mac: how to set the window close button modified state?

Tags: java, macos, javafx

I would like to be able to set the application modified state and have this reflected in the window close button (i.e., the black dot inside it).

I found a very nice overview (see:  http://nadeausoftware.com/node/90) of how to do this with Swing, but I'm using JavaFX so this is not applicable to me. I haven't found a way to do this yet. Any ideas?

Comment: There's a [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091596) that's going nowhere fast.

Comment: Thanks for that reference. Too bad it's not going anywhere though :disappointed: It's nice to be platform agnostic as a language, but some things just need to be implemented to make for “good” applications on a certain platform. This should be doable, even in a platform friendly way: just no-op the call on non-mac.