# Dirty windows in MacOS with JavaFX

Tags: java, macos, swing, javafx, macos-sierra

In Swing we used to set the small "dot" to indicate if a window is dirty (changes not saved) by using this :

```
myJFrame.getRootPane.putClientProperty("windowModified",Boolean.TRUE);
```

Is there a way to do the same thing in JavaFX ?

Comment: A little Googling led me to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34966398/2891664) and [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091596) which suggest this is not implemented in JavaFX yet.